# How does object_id assignment work?

Tags: ruby, internals

I'm playing around with Ruby's `.object_id` and noticed that, in several sequential sessions of irb,  I get these identical results:

```
false.object_id // 0
true.object_id // 2
nil.object_id // 4
100.object_id // 201
```

In fact, every integer's object_id seems to be ((value * 2) + 1).

On the other hand, a given string's object_id is never the same after exiting and re-running irb.

This raises several questions for me:

1. Is there a known scheme by which certain `object_id`s are determined? Are others basically random?
2. The ids for true, false, and nil, aren't sequential. Is there a way to ask what object is represented by a given id? (I'm curious what the other single-digit and ids are tied to.)
3. Could you (not that you should) write obfuscated Ruby where you use known object ids to refer to objects without naming them, like "object of id 201 + object of id 19" to mean "100 + 9"?

### Update

Using Andrew Grimm's suggestion, I tried discovering other "low id" objects, but found that:

- There don't appear to be any more even-numbered objects in this sequence - ids 6, 8, 10, etc don't point to anything.
- As implied by my earlier experiment, all the odd-numbered ids belong to numbers. Specifically, id 1 points to the number 0, 3 points to 1, 5 points to 2, and so forth.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In MRI the `object_id` of an object is the same as the `VALUE` that represents the object on the C level. For most kinds of objects this `VALUE` is a pointer to a location in memory where the actual object data is stored. Obviously this will be different during multiple runs because it only depends on where the system decided to allocate the memory, not on any property of the object itself.

However for performance reasons `true`, `false`, `nil` and `Fixnum`s are handled specially. For these objects there isn't actually a struct with the object's data in memory. All of the object's data is encoded in the `VALUE` itself. As you already figured out the values for `false`, `true`, `nil` and any `Fixnum` `i`, are `0`, `2`, `4` and `i*2+1` respectively.

The reason that this works is that on any systems that MRI runs on, `0`, `2`, `4` and `i*2+1` are never valid addresses for an object on the heap, so there's no overlap with pointers to object data.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning specific ruby implementations, I forgot about that being an issue.

Comment: @Nathan Long, I guess you would like to see [interesting lines of MRI source code](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/gc.c#3158).

Comment: symbols also seem to be a bit special, they have too low values to be a real address.. anybody knows the internals?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If you are still interested, this might help: http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/object.html Check for 'symbols' section.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Symbols are also pointers to the memory where their data is stored. The only thing special about symbols is that they're interned, which means that you can't have two different symbols with the same value. That is if you try to create a symbol that has the same value as an existing one, you instead get back a pointer to the existing symbol.

Comment: @sepp2k how is that possible that with every environment loaded any given symbol have exactly the same `object_id` ? (like nil is always 4 so :ruby is always 320328)

Comment: Worth noting that MRI stands for *Matzs' Ruby Interpreter*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI.

Answer (score 35):

Assigning Integer `(value * 2) + 1` and non-integers `(x * 2)` is analogous to [Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel), which describes how to assign infinitely more guests to an infinite hotel.

With regards to finding objects by their ID, there's `ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id)`. Unless your implementation doesn't have ObjectSpace.

Comment: `ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id)` is just.. awesome