# Why Ruby Instance Variables object_id s are weird

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, objectid

Below is the test case, I was just trying to do something with `dup` method. But I realized this weird behavior. I couldn't find any reasonable explanation.

```
class ObjectIdTest
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize
    @x, @y = 1, 2
  end

  def object_ids
    "x:#{@x.object_id}, y: #{@y.object_id}"
  end
end

class ObjectIdTestChild < ObjectIdTest
  attr_accessor :z
  def initialize
    @z = 3
  end

  def object_ids
    super + " z: #{@z.object_id}"
  end
end

oid1 = ObjectIdTest.new
oid2 = ObjectIdTestChild.new
p oid2.object_ids

oid3 = oid2.dup
p oid3.object_ids
```

**Output:**
"x:4, y: 4 z: 7"

"x:4, y: 4 z: 7"

1. Normally object ids' are longer (like *70322728590900*), why these are so smaller? (Are they relative or something like that?)
2. Why **x**'s and **y**'s object id  are the same?
3. Why **oid2** and **oid3** 's instance variables have the same object id?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218942/why-does-ruby-hash-a-fixnum-n-to-2n1

Comment: @steenslag I don't know if this Question can be counted as duplicate, but since I didn't know fixnums have defined object_ids, I couldn't find that answer. (which I couldn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Objects other than Fixnumber have bigger values. For instance:

```
 "hello".object_id #=> 70256148388440
 0x3FFFFFFFF.object_id #=> 34359738367
```

2 and 3 - Althought `dup` produces a shallow copy of an object, in this case that object happens to represent the same Fixnums. With Fixnums the same number has always the same object_id.  [Ruby Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html)