# Some `Fixnum` properties

Tags: ruby

I found the following features of `Fixnum` in [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html).

> `Fixnum` objects have immediate value. This means that when they are  assigned or passed as parameters, the actual object is passed, rather  than a reference to that object.

Can the same be shown in IRB? Hope then only it will be correctly understood by me?

> Assignment does not alias Fixnum objects.

What does it actually then?

> There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given  integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a  `Fixnum`.

Couldn't understand the reason not to add the `singleton` method with `Fixnum` object instances.

I gave some try to the second point as below:

```
a = 1                      # => 1
a.class                    # => Fixnum
b = a                      # => 1
b.class                    # => Fixnum
a == b                     # => true
a.equal? b                 # => true
a.object_id == b.object_id # => true
```

But still I am in confusion. Can anyone help me here to understand the core of those features please?

Comment: Sounds like Fixnum is the equivalent of .net's value types, or Java's primitives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ruby, most objects require memory to store their class and instance variables.  Once this memory is allocated, Ruby represents each object by this memory location.  When the object is assigned to a variable or passed to a function, it is the location of this memory that is passed, not the data at this memory.  Singleton methods make use of this.  When you define a singleton method, Ruby silently replaces the objects class with a new singleton class.  Because each object stores its class, Ruby can easily replace an object's class with a new class that implements the singleton methods (and inherits from the original class).

This is no longer true for objects that are immediate values: `true`, `false`, `nil`, all symbols, and integers that are small enough to fit within a Fixnum.  Ruby does not allocate memory for instances of these objects, it does not internally represent the objects as a location in memory.  Instead, it infers the instance of the object based on its internal representation.  What this means is twofold:

1. The class of each object is no longer stored in memory at a particular location, and is instead implicitly determined by the type of immediate object.  This is why Fixnums cannot have singleton methods.
2. Immediate objects with the same state (e.g., two Fixnums of integer 2378) are actually the same instance.  This is because the instance is determined by this state.

To get a better sense of this, consider the following operations on a Fixnum:

```
>> x = 3 + 7
=> 10
>> x.object_id == 10.object_id
=> true
>> x.object_id == (15-5).object_id
=> true
```

Now, consider them using strings:

```
>> x = "a" + "b"
=> "ab"
>> x.object_id == "ab".object_id
=> false
>> x.object_id == "Xab"[1...3].object_id
=> false
>> x == "ab"
=> true
>> x == "Xab"[1...3]
=> true
```

The reason the object ids of the Fixnums are equal is that they're immediate objects with the same internal representation.  The strings, on the other hand, exist in allocated memory.  The object id of each string is the location of its object state in memory.

#### Some low-level information

To understand this, you have to understand how Ruby (at least 1.8 and 1.9) treat Fixnums internally.  In Ruby, all objects are represented in C code by variables of type `VALUE`.  Ruby imposes the following requirements for `VALUE`:

1. The type VALUE is is the smallest integer of sufficient size to hold a pointer.  This means, in C, that `sizeof(VALUE) == sizeof(void*)`.
2. Any non-immediate object must be aligned on a 4-byte boundary.  This means that any object allocated by Ruby will have address `4*i` for some integer `i`.  This also means that all pointers have zero values in their two least significant bits.

The first requirement allows Ruby to store both pointers to objects and immediate values in a variable of type `VALUE`.  The second requirement allows Ruby to detect Fixnum and Symbol objects based on the two least significant bits.

To make this more concrete, consider the internal binary representation of a Ruby object `z`, which we'll call `Rz` in a 32-bit architecture:

```
MSB                                   LSB
  3           2            1            
 1098 7654 3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 32 10
 XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX AB CD
```

Ruby then interprets `Rz`, the representation of `z`, as follows:

1. If `D==1`, then `z` is a Fixnum.  The integer value of this Fixnum is stored in the upper 31 bits of the representation, and is recovered by performing an [arithmetic right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) to recover the signed integer stored in these bits.
2. Three special representations are tested (all with `D==0`)

   - if `Rz==0`, then `z` is `false`
   - if `Rz==2`, then `z` is `true`
   - if `Rz==4`, then `z` is `nil`
3. If `ABCD == 1110`, then 'z' is a Symbol.  The symbol is converted into a unique ID by right-shifting the eight least-significant bits (i.e., `z>>8` in C).  On 32-bit architectures, this allows 2^24 different IDs (over 10 million).  On 64-bit architectures, this allows 2^48 different IDs.
4. Otherwise, `Rz` represents an address in memory for an instance of a Ruby object, and the type of `z` is determined by the class information at that location.

Comment: OMG!! mind blowing... Thanks for such a detail explanation. Thank you very much. `+100` to you... :)

Comment: I have another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264633/confusion-with-some-bignum-propertie/15269278?noredirect=1#15269278) like this. If you have any more to say there or any better thing to share. You can there please :) your this explanation I enjoyed heavily :)

Answer (score 1):

Well...

1. This is an internal implementation detail on MRI. You see, in Ruby (on the C side of things), all Ruby objects are a `VALUE`. In most cases, a `VALUE` is a pointer to an object living on the stack. But the immediate values (Fixnums, true, false, nil, and something else) live in the `VALUE` where a pointer to an object would usually live.
2. It makes the variable the exact same object. Now, I have no idea how this works internally, because it assigns it to the `VALUE` itself, but it does.
3. Because every time I use the number `1` in my program, I'm using the same object. So if I define a singleton method on `1`, *every* place in my program, required programs, etc., will have that singleton method. And singleton methods are usually used for local monkeypatching. So, to prevent this, Ruby just doesn't let you.

Comment: Understood but an programmatic explanation could be better to understand :(

Comment: @Linuxios : [Regarding second point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218942/why-does-ruby-hash-a-fixnum-n-to-2n1/9219101#9219101)