# Confusion with some `Bignum` properties

Tags: ruby

From the doc [Bignum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Bignum.html#method-i-coerce)

The below properties I found:

> "While `Fixnum` values are immediate, `Bignum` objects are not —     assignment and parameter passing work with references to objects, not    the objects themselves."

*Actually as far as I know we are passing
   the  references to the objects,not the actual objects. But here I
   couldn't  follow the taste.*

> "When a calculation involving `Bignum` objects returns a result that will fit in a `Fixnum`, the result is automatically converted."

*In `C` I  found some rules such automatic conversions. But does the same applicable here also or other rules defined here specially for Ruby?*

> "For the purposes of the `bitwise` operations and `[]`, a Bignum is treated as if it were an infinite-length `bitstring` with 2’s complement  representation."

*Why `Bignum` only, not `Fixnum` or any others?*

Could anyone help me to understand this topic in details with some tiny code examples?

Answer (score 0):

[Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html) are immutable objects already instanced. You just have to use them. According the documentation:

> Fixnum objects have immediate value. This means that when they are assigned or passed as parameters, the actual object is passed, rather than a reference to that object. Assignment does not alias Fixnum objects. There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a Fixnum.

In another hand, Bignum is normal object. You need to instance them, you work with their reference, etc.

That means that when you're doing x = 5, the object is already created. You can check the object_id of primitives such as false or 0, 1, 2, ... There are all different, but always the same.

```
> 1.object_id
 => 3
> x = 1
 => 1
> x.object_id
 => 3
```

Two good articles on that topics:

- http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2009/04/21/object-ids-and-fixnums/
- http://www.rubyfleebie.com/understanding-fixnums/

For the conversion to Fixnum, there is explicit conversion triggered when it is detected that the result is in the domain covered by Fixnum. For instance, for sub two ints, when [returning the value](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/bignum.c#L1858) it calls the method bignorm doing that conversion if necessary (see the [comment above](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/bignum.c#L1852))

```
> a = 10000000000
 => 10000000000 
> a.class
 => Bignum 
> b = a / 10
 => 1000000000 
> b.class
 => Fixnum
```

For your last question, it's linked to 2's complement representation. There is several articles about that such as [the one for Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) or [the wikipedia page about bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). In fact, for Fixnum, the bitwise operations are directly operated by your processor, and it operates in a same way.