# Hash-related behavior mismatch between Ruby MRI 3.0.0 and 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I notices behavior changes between ruby MRI 3.0.0 and 3.0.1, but can't see the reason in the changelog (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/compare/v3_0_0...v3_0_1)

Consider the following simple "value object" class:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Locale
  attr_reader :code

  delegate :to_s, :to_sym, :hash, to: :code

  def initialize(code:)
    @code = code
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.respond_to?(:to_sym) && to_sym == other.to_sym
  end
  alias == eql?
end
```

Ruby 3.0.0:

```rb
[9] pry(main)> p RUBY_VERSION; ((1..1000).to_a + [:en, "en"]).to_set.include?(Locale.new(code: :en))
"3.0.0"
false
```

Ruby 3.0.1:

```rb
[6] pry(main)> p RUBY_VERSION; ((1..1000).to_a + [:en, "en"]).to_set.include?(Locale.new(code: :en))
"3.0.1"
true
```

I believe it might be related to hash-as-array optimization for small hashes, because

```rb
[13] pry(main)> p RUBY_VERSION; ([:en, "en"]).to_set.include?(Locale.new(code: :en))
"3.0.0"
true
```

Here's plain ruby script which produces (sometimes! it's flaky) different results on 3.0.0 and 3.0.1:

```rb
raise unless RUBY_VERSION == "3.0.0" || RUBY_VERSION == "3.0.1"

require "set"

class Locale
  attr_reader :code

  def initialize(code:)
    @code = code
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.respond_to?(:to_sym) && to_sym == other.to_sym
  end
  alias == eql?

  def to_sym
    code.to_sym
  end

  def hash
    code.hash
  end
end

p RUBY_VERSION
p Set.new(((1..1000).to_a + [:ru, :en])).include?(Locale.new(code: :en))
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Does it work without the `to_set`? I wonder if the issue is because of how the `hash` method works, or if it is about the implementation of `eql?`. Did you compare the generated hash values?

Comment: ```ruby
[1] pry(main)> RUBY_VERSION
"3.0.1"
[2] pry(main)> [:es, :en].include?(Locale.new(code: :en))
false
[3] pry(main)> [:es, :en].to_set.include?(Locale.new(code: :en))
true
```

surprisingly, plain arrays also return false -- it does not event call `eql?` nor `==`

Comment: @spickermann `Locale(code: :en).hash` equals to `:en.hash` (`#hash` is delegated)

Comment: Note that `Locale.new(code: :en) == :en` is calls `==` on the `Locale` instance. But :en == Locale.new(code: :en)`calls `==` on the Symbol `:en`. It depends on the internal order in which `include?` compares the element with the argument.

Comment: Yeah, just figured out it by myself, thanks :) But it still does not resolve the mystery around sets

Comment: @engineersmnky I added ad MRE whch can be run on pure ruby (without rails environment). Note that it's flaky, i.e. you should run it multiple times. Running on 3.0.0 will yield true/false depending on unknown condition. Running on 3.0.1 will always print `true`

Comment: The change is likely caused by the second commit on the linked page: [b2beb8586e930c168af434d6545f75d76123192b](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/b2beb8586e930c168af434d6545f75d76123192b). See [Bug #17488](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17488) for more details. `3.0.0` seems to be only known version with this bug.

Comment: @cremno You should add this as an answer (and likely quote the relevant parts form the issue).

Answer (score 2):

The change in behavior is likely caused by the second commit on the linked page: [b2beb8586e930c168af434d6545f75d76123192b](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/b2beb8586e930c168af434d6545f75d76123192b).

The commit message references [Bug #17488](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17488). Its title is *Regression in Ruby 3: Hash#key? is non-deterministic when argument uses DelegateClass*. So we already have delegates, hashes and non-deterministic (flaky) results. And according the notes it affects only version `3.0.0` since the fix was backported to `3.0`, in particular `3.0.1`, and `2.7` and earlier are apparently unaffected. That sounds like your observation!

nobu (Nobuyoshi Nakada) who found and fixed the bug wrote:

> The cause was that `hnum <<= 1; hnum = RSHIFT(hnum, 1);` just
> clears/sets the MSB, but not the next bit, so it can exceed Fixnum
> limits. I'm not sure why it didn't happen before the commit.

So the actual reason is still unknown but the code was wrong before and [this change](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/03670392f46f00a4f92c41a3c7ea6215138037a6) between `2.7.0` and `3.0.0` change exposed it.

So-called fixnums are an implementation detail (nowadays better hidden to the Ruby world - there used to be a `Fixnum` class). They're basically 31-bit or 63-bit signed integers but if you want to know more about them read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261335/4231385), for example.

Answer (score 0):

you could redefine the eql? method in your Locale class to only consider other Locale objects as potentially equal:

```
def eql?(other)
  other.is_a?(Locale) && code.to_sym == other.code.to_sym
end
```

This change should make the behavior of your Locale class consistent across different Ruby versions.

Comment: That's true, but I actually want to figure out what exactly changed in ruby implementation to know possible impact. To add some context, I18n uses set-based collection of locale codes (i.e. `:en`) and checks inclusion of locale provided via `I18n.t(..., locale: Locale.new(code: :en))`. Checking class in `eql?` would definetely break it.

Comment: oh okay then. Somebody else will come up with the answer.