# Variable in else condition assumed nil value

Tags: ruby, local-variables

This is something strange I've figured out in ruby 1.9.3.

Here is the code:

```
>> r = true
>> if r
>>   a  = "hello"
>> else
>>   b = "hello"
>> end
```

Now the value of `a` is "hello":

```
>> a
=> "hello"
```

And strangely the value of `b` is nil

```
>> b
=> nil
```

Since `b` is nowhere in the scene, it should be undeclared.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, not when the assignment occurs:

```
=> foo
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
=> if false
=>   foo = "bar" # does not assign to foo
=> end
=> nil
=> foo
=> nil
```

Comment: It is not initialized. That's why it evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: For the actual source of this quote: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods

Answer (score 3):

Variable declarations take effect even if the branch where the assignment takes place is never reached.

Comment: @Patritosh: I just ran your code, then ran `puts b.object_id
# => 70364348734500`.  As you see, the object `b` was created and given the value `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That's strange. What Ruby implementation are you using? It's not required by the spec, but on all even remotely popular Ruby implementations (MRI, YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, MRuby, Ruby.NET, XRuby, MagLev, MacRuby, Cardinal, Topaz, BlueRuby, Ruby GoLightly, tinyrb), the `object_id` of `nil` is `4`.

Comment: @Jörg, odd indeed! It should have been `b.object_id # => 8`.  (I'm using MRI 2.0.0).  So how did I get 70364348734500?  It was an IRB gotcha.  I had used the variable `b` to test something else earlier, and neglected to check it's value after running the asker's code and `puts b.object_id `.  Why didn't I notice something was amiss?  No explanation for that.  `object_id` of `nil` was [changed to 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506763/why-was-the-object-id-for-true-and-nil-changed-in-ruby2-0) in 2.0.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about the extra tag bit for flonums in YARV 2.0. (BTW: object IDs are a private internal implementation detail of a particular Ruby implementation. They are not guaranteed to be the same on different implementations. They are not even guaranteed to be the same across several runs of the same program. So, when you say that the ID of `nil` was changed in 2.0, what you specifically mean is that it was changed in *YARV 2.0*, not in *Ruby 2.0*. Ruby 2.0 doesn't make any guarantees about the value of `object_id` for `nil` or any other object.)

Comment: @Jörg, you are a stickler (a very desirable trait in your profession, imo--I say "your" because for me coding is just a hobby).  And thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is explained in the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods), and it is valid for any version of Ruby, not just 1.9:

> The local variable is created when the parser encounters the
>   assignment, **not when the assignment occurs**.

This means that if the parser sees an assignment in the code it creates the local variable even if the assignment will never really occur. In this case the value referenced by the variable is `nil`:

```
if true
  a = 0
else
  b = 0
end

p local_variables
# => [:a, :b]

p a
# => 0

p b
# => nil
```