# Why can the variables in if-block initialize?

Tags: ruby

`y` has been defined in if block, it will be `nil`. If that is removed, it gives an error: "undefined local variable or method `y' for main:Object".

```
if false
  y = 'hi'
end
puts y
```

Why can the variables in if-block initialize?

Comment: Where you are trying out your code? In irb it will never give such error if you simply define `y = 'hi'`. And here your if block is never executed as the condition is always false

Comment: @Abhi It's not quite that simple, though; OP is asking how it's defined at *all*, not just why it's `nil`.

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180760/variable-in-else-condition-assumed-nil-value (itself marked as duplicate)

Comment: @Dave I got the point after referring to the duplicate question. Thanks