# Capturing errors for individual forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to capture validation errors for individual forms as I have many on one page.

I am giving each form its own unique id by using `object_id`

```
<% object = @document || Document.new %>
<%= form_for object, :html => { id: object.object_id.to_s } do |f| %>
```

But if i do this to capture errors the same error message will appear on all my forms

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  # errors
<% end %>
```

I have tried

```
<% if object.object_id.errors.any? %>
```

But i get

```
undefined method `errors' for 59187740:Fixnum
```

Is there a way around this please

Thanks

Edit

i have just noticed that the form id changes when validation fails as the page reloads, so that explains why the object cannot be found.

How can i keep the form id the same?

Answer (score 0):

If really depends on what you want to do with the errors:

**You want to show them for each form:**

```
<%= form_for some_object, do |f1| %>
  <%= f1.error_messages %>
  <%= # f1 magic %>

<%= form_for other_object, do |f2| %>
  <%= f2.error_messages %>
  <%= # f2 magic %>
```

**You want to access them for each object:**

just call `object.errors`: `some_object.errors`

**What isn't working for you:**

Calling `object_id` on an `object` access its `id` which is a number (`FixNum`). You are trying to call a method/access an attribute on a `FixNum` which does not exist.

**You just want some persistent ID for your form**

I assume that your `object` is coming from a database and already has an ID. So why don't you just use `object.id`? Every time Rails create an ActiveRecord object for you from the DB, that object gets a new `object_id`. So it is only logical that the ID doesn't stay the same since you have a new `object` in memory. Read more about it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430487/2295964

Comment: thanks for your answer..Is there a way to assign a number to the form id (maybe iterate through an array), so that when the form fails validation say, the same id will be assigned.. My problem is when creating a new object

Comment: @Richlewis can you provide more information about how your forms are created and structured?

Comment: What else would you like to see?