# get the database object from it's hexadecimal object_id representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'some_method?' for #<Customer:0x007f8a2c5d7d80>
```

`Customer` is a db-backed AR model.
Any way I can actually know which customer is that judging by `0x007f8a2c5d7d80`?

How do I translate it into something reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430280/how-does-object-id-assignment-work) answers my question.

There is no way to determine, which object exactly this was:

> Obviously this will be different during multiple runs because it only
>   depends on where the system decided to allocate the memory, not on any
>   property of the object itself.

There's an awesome method - [ObjectSpace#`_id2ref`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-_id2ref) - it allows to ***actually find*** the object by it's `object_id`:

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something :)

```
a = SomethingClass.new
a
# => #<SomethingClass:0x005641a0a3bed8>

0x005641a0a3bed8
#=> 94839867948760

a.object_id * 2
#=> 94839867948760
```

So in decimal this "werid" code is just doubled `object_id`